# ListBox SelectedItem never sets

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a list box inside a column of a data grid. Cars is a list of items inside an observable collection (BuyersCollection).

- The columns are getting populated, but the SelectedCar is never set.
- Also, if I select an item from one list in a row and then select a
  list item from another row, then both of them are selected in the
  grid. Is there a way to only select the latest one?

```xaml
<telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding BuyersCollection}"   
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Cars">
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <telerik:RadListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCar,Mode=TwoWay,Source={StaticResource CarsViewModel}}" DisplayMemberPath="name" SelectionMode="Single">
```

```cs
public Car SelectedCar
{
    get
    {
        return selectedCar;
    }
    set
    {
        if (selectedCar != value)
        {
            selectedCar = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedCar));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does adding `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to `SelectedItem` help?

Comment: Definately a binding scope issue. Notice how you binded you collection without using `Source={StaticResource CarsViewModel}` like in `SelectedItem` when actually the have the same source.

Comment: Where is the SelectedCar property defined? And what type is BuyersCollection?

Comment: @mm8 in the SelectedCar is in CarsViewModel, BuyersColelction is an ObservableColection of Buyers. A Buyer has a list of Cars

Comment: @MattBeldon that helped thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check if your binding scope is correct. The binding on SelectedCar is inside a Datatemplate. That means that each of your 'buyer' in your buyercollections has a Collection of cars : "Cars" and a car property called 'Selected car'.